# Break string down into chunks of three, but with a minimum count of two

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, match

I need to break down a string of digits into chunks of three, but I cannot allow a chunk to contain only one digit, it must contain at least two.

For example

`[123],[456],[7]` - this is not acceptable because `7` is left on it's own

`[123],[45],[67]` - this is the acceptable solution

I've got almost there, but I'm not sure how to handle making sure that there are at least two digits.

Here is my solution, which breaks the string down into three parts but doesn't account for a minimum digit count:

```
function solution(s) {
    var number = s.replace(/\D/g, '');
    number = number.match(/.{1,3}/g); // breaks down into threes
    number = number.join('-');
    return number;
}
```

Here's a codepen to see it in action: http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/mPobNb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with lookahead.

The [Positive Lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) looks for the pattern after the equal sign, but does not include it in the match.

> **x(?=y)**
>
> Matches 'x' only if 'x' is followed by 'y'. This is called a lookahead.
>
> For example, `/Jack(?=Sprat)/` matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat'. `/Jack(?=Sprat|Frost)/` matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat' or 'Frost'. However, neither 'Sprat' nor 'Frost' is part of the match results.

[Online RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/yU0oP0/1)

```js
function format(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/\d{2,3}(?=..)/g, '$&-');
}

document.write(format(123456789) + '<br>');
document.write(format(12345678901) + '<br>');
document.write(format(1234567) + '<br>');
```

Edit

While I do not find, that an extra loop via an array is necessary, this proposal gives you the wanted step with [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for later joining the array with the following regular expression:

> `/.{2,3}(?=..)|.+/g`
>
> - `1st` Alternative: `.{2,3}(?=..)`
>     
>
>   - `.{2,3}` **matches any character (except newline)**
>       `Quantifier:` `{2,3}` Between `2` and `3` times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
>   - `(?=..)` **Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched**
>       `.` matches any character (except newline)
>       `.` matches any character (except newline)
> - `2nd` Alternative: `.+`
>
>   - `.+` **matches any character (except newline)**
>       `Quantifier:` `+` Between `one` and `unlimited` times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
> - `g modifier`: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

```js
var a, i, s = '';

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    s += i;
    a = s.match(/.{2,3}(?=..)|.+/g);
    document.write(a.join('-') + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you break this down to just the part that handles the lookahead? Similar to how I have it broken down into three different lines. It just makes it easier for me to learn than seeing it all combined.

Comment: Also I tried your solution, and it removes the last two numbers of the string which isn't right. All numbers need to be included: http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/mPobNb

Comment: you are using `match` instead of `replace`, like my proposal above. `match` returns only the matched part, without the rest. in your case, i would do it in one step with `replace`.

Comment: Can you please break down the given answer so that it just shows the part that is handling dividing up the string please. I am trying to learn and your answer is confusing as I am struggling to see which part is the exact solution. Please don't include handling the special char removal on the same line. Please use my example in OP.

Comment: Here is my example again, which does not work. http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/qZvBbg

Comment: Please? Do you have any advice to offer on what I have put in the codepen?

Comment: @user1486133 Nina's solution works, here is the updated pen http://codepen.io/gurvinder372/pen/ONqJxb